# how to addEventListener with the back button and reload the page?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using angular to build a single page application,but when user click the back button with the browser.it causes some problems.So I need to reload the page.here is my solution:

```
detectBack =
  initialize: ()->
    window.addEventListener('hashchange',()->
      this.history.replaceState('hasHash', '', '');
    ,false)
    window.addEventListener('popstate',(e)->
      if e.state
        this.location.reload();
    ,false)
detectBack.initialize()
```

but it doesnt work well in IE.In fact, the whole application cannot be used in IE 
Is there any solution with angularjs to make sure I can listen the event when user click the back button then I can reload the page?

Comment: where is the AngularJS code?

Comment: I just change another way ,when people back to url:`localhost://pageA?a=11` from url:`localhost://pageA?a=22`.they are in the same route .so I judge the url like this `$rootScope.$on '$stateChangeStart', (evt, next, curr) ->
      if next.name == $state.current.name then
        window.location.reload()`